# Exctraction of the Proof from Fitting's leanTap Prolog Prover

Tags: algorithm, prolog, swi-prolog

Here is the SWI-Prolog  code of  [Fitting's leanTap revisited](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2240690_leanTAP_revisited):

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(statistics)).

% :- use_module(library(dom)).
% operator definitions (TPTP syntax)

:- op( 500, fy, ~).             % negation
:- op(1000, xfy, &).    % conjunction
:- op(1100, xfy, '|').  % disjunction
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % conditional
:- op(1120, xfy, <=>).  % biconditional

/*
Next, a classification of formula types,
& instances.
*/

type(X & Y, conj, X, Y).
type(~(X & Y), disj, ~ X, ~ Y).
type(X | Y, disj, X, Y).
type(~(X | Y), conj, ~ X, ~ Y).
type(X => Y, disj, ~ X, Y).
type(~(X => Y), conj, X, ~ Y).
type(X <=> Y, disj, X & Y, ~ X & ~ Y).
type(~(X <=> Y), disj, X & ~ Y, ~ X & Y).
type(~ (~ (X)), doub, X, _).
/*
Now the heart of the matter.
thm(Lambda, Gamma) :-
the sequent Lambda --> Gamma is provable.
*/

thm(Lambda, [Doubleneg | Gamma]) :- 
        type(Doubleneg, doub, X, _), !,
        thm(Lambda, [X | Gamma]).

thm(Lambda, [Beta | Gamma]) :-
        type(Beta, disj, Beta1, Beta2), !,
        thm(Lambda, [Beta1, Beta2 | Gamma]).

thm(Lambda, [Alpha | Gamma]) :-
        type(Alpha, conj, Alpha1, Alpha2), !,
        thm(Lambda, [Alpha1 | Gamma]), !,
        thm(Lambda, [Alpha2 | Gamma]).

thm([L1|Lambda], [L2|_]) :-
        (
          L1 = L2, !
        ;
          thm(Lambda, [L2])
        ).

thm(Lambda, [~ L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([L | Lambda], Gamma), !.

thm(Lambda, [L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([~ L | Lambda], Gamma), !.
/*
Finally, the driver.
*/
prove(X) :-
time(thm([], [X])).
```

This code according to Fitting provides a sequent calculus. I have tried to change minimally this code to get a Prolog Print of each proof, with input prove(X, Proof), following the  structure of Jen Otten's prover (online [here](https://www.philipzucker.com/javascript-automated-proving/)
and [here](https://www.vidal-rosset.net/sequent_calculus_prover_with_antisequents_for_classical_propositional_logic.html)):

```
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
% leanseq.pl - A sequent calculus prover implemented in Prolog
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
:- use_module(library(lists)).

% operator definitions (TPTP syntax)

:- op( 500, fy, ~).     % negation
:- op(1000, xfy, &).    % conjunction
:- op(1100, xfy, '|').  % disjunction
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % implication

% -----------------------------------------------------------------
provable(F, P) :- time(prove([] > [F], P)).
% -----------------------------------------------------------------

% axiom
prove(G > D, ax(G > D, A)) :- member(A,G), member(B,D), A == B, !.

% conjunction
prove(G > D, land(G > D, P) ) :- select1( (A & B) ,G,G1), !,
                prove([A , B | G1] > D, P).

prove(G > D, rand(G > D, P1,P2)) :- select1( (A & B) ,D,D1), !,
                prove(G > [A|D1], P1), prove(G > [B|D1], P2).

% disjunction
prove(G > D, lor(G > D, P1,P2)) :- select1((A | B),G,G1), !,
                prove([A|G1] > D, P1), prove([B|G1] > D, P2).

prove(G > D, ror(G > D, P)) :- select1( (A | B),D,D1), !,
                prove(G > [A,B|D1], P ).

% implication
prove(G > D, limpl(G > D, P1,P2)) :- select1((A => B),G,G1), !,
                prove(G1 > [A|D], P1), prove([B|G1] > D, P2).

prove(G > D, rimpl(G > D, P)) :- select1((A => B),D,D1), !,
                prove([A|G] > [B|D1], P).

% negation
prove(G > D, lneg(G > D, P)) :- select1( ~A,G,G1), !,
                prove(G1 > [A|D], P).

prove(G > D, rneg(G > D, P)) :- select1(~A ,D,D1), !,
                prove([A|G] > D1, P).

% -----------------------------------------------------------------
select1(X,L,L1) :- append(L2,[X|L3],L), append(L2,L3,L1).
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example :

> - provable((p => p), Proof).
>   % 22 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (95% CPU, 1132503 Lips)
>   *Proof* = rimpl([]>[(p=>p)], ax([p]>[p], p))

But all my tentatives  to get from Fitting's prover (that is complete) a prover that provides a proof like *Proof* above have failed. Any help that could put me on the right track would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean "extract", and not primarily "print".

Comment: Yes, you are right !

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works smoothly and is very fast, with label for sequent rules corresponding to Fitting's sequent calculus that Fitting calls *dirseq* :

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(statistics)).

% :- use_module(library(dom)).
% operator definitions (TPTP syntax)

:- op( 500, fy, ~).             % negation
:- op(1000, xfy, &).    % conjunction
:- op(1100, xfy, '|').  % disjunction
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % conditional
:- op(1120, xfy, <=>).  % biconditional

/*
Next, a classification of formula types,
& instances.
*/

type((X & Y), conj, X, Y).
type(~((X | Y)), conj, ~ X, ~ Y).
type(~((X => Y)), conj, X, ~ Y).
type((X <=> Y), conj,  (~ X | Y),  (X | ~ Y)).
type(~((X <=> Y)), conj, (X |  Y), (~ X | ~ Y)).
type(~ (~ (X)), doub, X, _).
type((X => Y), disj, ~ X, Y).
type(~((X & Y)), disj, ~ X, ~ Y).
type((X | Y), disj, X, Y).

/*
Now the heart of the matter.
thm(Lambda, Gamma) :-
the sequent Lambda --> Gamma is provable.
*/

thm(Lambda > [Alpha | Gamma], R) :-
        type(Alpha, conj, Alpha1, Alpha2), !,
        thm(Lambda > [Alpha1 | Gamma],P), !,
        thm(Lambda > [Alpha2 | Gamma],Q),
        R = alpha(Lambda >  [Alpha | Gamma],(P & Q)).

thm(Lambda >  [Beta | Gamma], R) :-
        type(Beta, disj, Beta1, Beta2), !,
        thm(Lambda > [Beta1, Beta2 | Gamma],P),
        R = beta(Lambda >  [Beta | Gamma], P).

thm(Lambda > [Doubleneg | Gamma], R) :- 
        type(Doubleneg, doub, X, Gamma), !,
        thm(Lambda > [X | Gamma], P),
        R =  dn(Lambda > [Doubleneg | Gamma], P).

thm(Lambda > [L|Gamma], R) :-
        member(L, Lambda), !,
        R = ax(Lambda >  [L|Gamma], ax).

thm(Lambda >  [~ L | Gamma], R) :- !,
         thm([L | Lambda] >  Gamma, P),
         R = duality(Lambda >  [~ L | Gamma], P).
        
thm(Lambda > [L | Gamma], R)  :-
        thm([~ L | Lambda] >  Gamma, P),
        R = duality(Lambda > [L | Gamma], P).

/*
Finally, the driver.
*/

provable(X, R) :-
time(thm([] > [X], R)).
```

Many thanks for the help that I have received !

Comment: @RúbenDias : you are right and I was wrong. I deleted my reply to your remark.

Comment: Probably a small typo where you have R = duality(Lambda >  [~ L | Gamma], P) twice. Also move R = ... always after the cut, like in the member rule.

Comment: Wang McCarthy needs another proof extraction, like the ax rule will not show Gamma, this needs to be improved as well.

Comment: @RúbenDias , many thanks for these corrections. That's very helpful !

Answer (score 1):

The Fitting code has some silly placement of cuts,
generating spurious choice points, and an unnecessary
recursion redoing all the pattern matching, instead of

directly using member/2. If you implement it more closely to
the original Wang McCarthy from the [LISP 1.5 Manual](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) at
page 44 ff, you get a little bit more speed:

```
/* Fitting */
?- time((between(1,100,_), test, fail; true)).
% 3,358,200 inferences, 0.297 CPU in 0.295 seconds (101% CPU, 11311832 Lips)
true.

/* Wang McCarthy */
?- time((between(1,100,_), test2, fail; true)).
% 2,802,900 inferences, 0.203 CPU in 0.209 seconds (97% CPU, 13798892 Lips)
true.
```

To arrive at Wang McCarthy replace this here from Fitting:

```
/* Fitting */
thm([L1|Lambda], [L2|_]) :-
        (
          L1 = L2, !
        ;
          thm(Lambda, [L2])
        ).

thm(Lambda, [~ L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([L | Lambda], Gamma), !.

thm(Lambda, [L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([~ L | Lambda], Gamma), !.
```

By this here:

```
/* Wang McCarthy */
thm2(Lambda, [L|_]) :- member(L, Lambda), !.

thm2(Lambda, [~ L | Gamma]) :- !,
        thm2([L | Lambda], Gamma).

thm2(Lambda, [L | Gamma]) :-
        thm2([~ L | Lambda], Gamma).
```

As a test case I was running a collection of
principia mathematica tautologies.

Comment: Congratulations ! It is a really nice improvement of Fitting's program.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly you can easily add [look-ahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver#CDCL_solvers) (forward
checking, unit propagation) to Melvin Fittings prover.
Just take this end-phase:

```
/* Fitting */
thm([L1|Lambda], [L2|_]) :-
        (
          L1 = L2, !
        ;
          thm(Lambda, [L2])
        ).

thm(Lambda, [~ L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([L | Lambda], Gamma), !.

thm(Lambda, [L | Gamma]) :-
        thm([~ L | Lambda], Gamma), !.
```

And replace it by this end-phase:

```
/* Fitting + fCube Simplification */
thm(_, [1 | _)] :- !.

thm(_, [0 | Gamma]) :- !,
   thm2(_, Gamma).

thm2(_, [L| Gamma]) :-
   opposite2(L, R),
   reduce(Gamma, R, Gamma2),
   thm2(_, Gamma2).
```

As can be seen in the above, the list `Lambda`
is even not anymore used. The predicate `reduce/2` is
supposed to partially evaluate the list `Gamma`, under

the assumption that R is true. Here are some timings
for the test case SYN007+1.014.p:

```
/* Fitting */
% 12,779,502 inferences, 0.813 CPU in 0.826 seconds (98% CPU, 15728618 Lips)

/* Fitting + fCube Simplification */
% 1,203,958 inferences, 0.109 CPU in 0.098 seconds (112% CPU, 11007616 Lips)
```

Comment: Very interesting ! Many thanks !